# Jekyll Collection of _posts Not Rendering on _site

Tags: ruby, jekyll, posts, netlify

can someone help me?

I have a Jekyll site on netlify (http://127.0.0.1:4000/) that is working great.

I followed [this](https://blog.mvp-space.com/10-steps-to-configure-jekyll-with-netlify-as-a-cms-d754d73ea731) tutorial to create a Jekyll admin path with CMS (http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin) to administrate the posts I want to write.

Basically, I created a new `admin` folder with two files, `index.html` and `config.yml`. My new file `config.yml` is like so...

[image]

It is working properly, I can create and update the posts on the `_posts` folder as expected.

Wherever, I'm trying to create a blog on a subpath of that site, like http://127.0.0.1:4000/blog for loop through the posts on `_posts` on such path, but I doing something wrong and can't figure out what is it.

The last thing I tried was to create a collection for the posts on the main file `_config.yml` like so...

[image]

I tried two `permalinks`, add/remove the `folder` and add `layout`, but I think I'm forgetting something.

To help you guys understand the whole project, my `index.html` has

```
---
layout: default
---
```

and the `layout default` is on the folder `_layouts` and contains many imports that are on the folder `_includes`.

[image]

Finally, I tied to loop through the collection of `_posts` on `index.html` adding code like bellow on the file `posts_list.html` that was imported as you can see above...

```
<h1>Latest Posts</h1>

<ul>
  {% for p in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a>
      <!-- {{ p.excerpt }} -->

    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and also creating a new `html` file called `posts.html` on the same folder of `index.html` with the same code above, but in both cases the posts are not rendering.

Finally, this is my whole project...

[image]

If you want more info about what I'm doing, just ask,

Thanks for helping me...

[**UPDATE 1**]

My posts are `.md` files, here is an example...

[image]

As you can see I also created some extra layouts, one for compiling all posts `blog` and another for show the post itself `post`.

Comment: You commented an essential part of your defaults. Remove the # characters from the defaults in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension to .md (on your posts and index file) and add frontmatter, referencing your template. Your posts.md and index.md files should look like this:

```
---
layout: default
---
```

Check for errors... if there are none it should output just fine.

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you for sharing your code at https://github.com/nielsenrechia/nr.github.io.

I see that you created random comments in your config file. They mess things up. Clean up your config file and use the right indents and new lines. Check out the Jekyll documentation at https://jekyllrb.com/ for help. Further you seem to reference your posts by calling `site._posts`. That should be `site.posts`. Finally, you do not need to specify the posts collection in the config file. It is assumed that it exists and uses the _posts folder.

Here is an image of the working posts section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JoostS, but my posts are .md file. I changed my index.html and posts.html for .md but both compiles without error and not rendering the posts yet. I'm thinking that my problem is with collection and/or routes.

Comment: Hi @JoostS, I tried removing comments but still the same. The posts are not rendering... Thanks

Comment: I'm practically giving up creating the blog this way, I left the public repository, if anyone can help me thank you. https://github.com/nielsenrechia/nr.github.io I tried many ways but it didn't works.

Comment: When you remove the multilanguage plugin it works. I have tested that. You need to figure out what the author of the plugin wants with posts. They do no longer work in the normal way. I would remove the plugin. I think it is horribly complex.